# How to make a bash script for uploading to git

Tags: git, bash

I am using mac osx, and would like to make a simple bash script for uploading changed files to my github repository.

It should ask for my comments to the files that i'm committing something like:

```
git add .
git commit -m 'prompt for comments'
git push origin master
```

I don't know how to make the script, i just want to do it via terminal with a single command.

any help would be much appreciated.

I do know how to make aliases in my .bash_profiles though :-)

Thanks.

Comment: Start with `help read` and google "bash user input"

Comment: Leave the `-m` option off `commit`, and `git commit` itself will simply open your preferred editor to enter the commit message. No need to prompt and read it separately.

Answer (score 6):

You may try:

```
#!/bin/bash  
git add .  
read -p "Commit description: " desc  
git commit -m "$desc"
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a super simple solution that's more generic than bash (more portable):

```
#!/bin/sh
printf "Commit msg: "
read msg
git commit -am "$msg"
git push origin master
```

It doesn't do `git add` to add new files but `-a` adds tracked files to be staged for commit. This is often what one wants. If you *really* want to do `git add .` just add that line and remove the `a` from options to `git commit`.

Comment: It doesn't work. I get this:

'{~} -> gitup
Commit msg: change
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git'